# Python program that checks output of another python program

Tags: python

I am trying to code a python program which can run another python program multiple times and automatically check its output for some desired result.

How can I code this in python 3 ?

Comment: What Operating system is it? depending on that you need to open your cmd prompt or terminal and run the file e.g. for linux `python hellloworld.py` where python is your python binary

Comment: It's windows 10

Comment: So you can run helloworld.py from terminal right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for letting you know that you don't need another program to check the output of a program running multiple times. You can do it in the same file as well. You can do it by using a while loop.

While Loop syntax :

```
while expression:
    # Block of Code
```

And if you really want a python program which runs another python program and checks its output then you can use **subprocess** module.

The code that can make you understand is.

```
# Importing subprocess 
import subprocess

# Your command 
cmd = "python other_script.py"

# Starting process
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Getting the output and errors of the program
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

# Printing the output
print(stdout)
```

Again you need to use while loop which checks runs another program multiple times and checks it's output.

Comment: sorry, but it says AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'PIPE'
what can i do about this?

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks for coming up with the error. Actually, I had added an extra PIPE word that's why it was giving an error. Now, it's fixed you can check the code. It's running perfectly